# Is Facebook now requiring an image when providing a link to a status update?

Tags: image, facebook-graph-api, posting

I've received the following error twice today when trying to post a status update via the graph API. This is also the first time it shows up.

(#100) img objects must have valid 'src' and 'href'

The post I am trying to send contains a message as well as the attachment with title, caption, description and link, but no image. I do have the image field in my post variables, but it is left empty. This has worked very well for months. Is Facebook now requiring an image when an attachment and a link is provided? Is anyone else getting this?

Answer (score 0):

Just omit the empty image field in your post.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also getting this error since recently.

If I omit the empty image field (it should be called "picture", right?) it works, but then Facebook chooses a random image from the linked web page, and that's what I'm trying to avoid putting an empty field. Maybe there's another way to do it nowdays.